# Spring MVC - fetching wrong message bundle

Tags: java, spring, jsp, liferay, portlet

I have a strange problem using **Spring MVC** message bundles: the wrong message bundle file is being fetched. I have double-checked, and in my Java controller class I have the **fr_FR** locale, but Spring tags (`appContext.getMessage(code, null, locale);` in the class as well) return me English messages!

What is going on?

I am developing portlets for Liferay Portal. Let me show you parts of my code:

in **applicationContext.xml**:

```xml
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

in my **JSPs** I have code looking like this:

```xml
... 
<spring:message code="button.help"/> 
...
```

and the paths to my messages look like this:

**development:**

- /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties  (English, default)
- /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/messages_fr.properties

**deployed in Tomcat**

- /webapps/MY_APP/WEB-INF/classes/messages.properties
- /webapps/MY_APP/WEB-INF/classes/messages_fr.properties

Comment: The problem can have 3 causes: the french properties file is not loaded, or for some reason the tag uses the english local, or the frensh message file does not contains the key.

Comment: The strangest thing is that only this particular portlet localization doesnt work.. Every other portlet works just fine. Both have identical keys - none is missing.

Comment: I dont know portlets well, but did you configured the local interceptors. Spring Referrence Chapter 15.6 http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-localeresolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue when my localized message file had a bad unicode character (the 
\uXXX form).

Neither Java, Spring nor Tomcat did write an information about it, no feedback at all.

After fixing the file, everything **suddenly** started to work.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the language (to fr_FR ) in your browser. In firefox version that I use, its at

`Edit ->Preferences -> Content -> Langauges`

And use the move-up or move-down buttons to have fr_FR as the top preference.

This makes the browser send requests with the prefered locale set.

Comment: But I have it set to French. Every possible debug output prints that I have a fr_FR locale selected (by the http request)!

If I remove the messages.properties file, I get errors that messages couldn't be found.

Comment: I guess your property file name should be messages_fr_FR.properties instead of messages_fr.properties

Comment: as an addition can you try configuring a locale resolver ? like in the last answer here http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?15369-Getting-Locale-to-work.

Comment: The strangest thing is that only this particular portlet localization doesnt work.. Every other portlet works just fine...

Answer (score 0):

You must have an interceptor in applicationContext like

```xml
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

You also need

```xml
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"/>
```

On the first JSP page of my project I gave a choice for languages like that:

```html
<span style="float: right"> <a href="?lang=en">en</a> | <a
        href="?lang=fr">fr</a> </span>
```

Please tell me if this helped you.

P.S. My messages_*.properties files are in a source folder src/main/resources, not in webapp, I don't know if this matters.

P.P.S. Useful tutorial here:
http://springbyexample.org/examples/basic-webapp-internationalization.html

I would like to add also that at the beginning of your xml you should have stuff like:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
```

It is necessary in order to recognize the prefixes such as mvc. Make sure you have it.

Comment: property name="basename" or **basenames**?

Comment: It's basename, not basenames.

Answer (score 0):

Frist you have to make sure that liferay supports the locale you want. In addition you have to add your supported locales in the portlet.xml for each portlet.

`portlet.xml`:

```xml
<portlet>
   ...
   <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
   <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
   ...
</portlet>
```

If you miss one of both it just won't work. Check if you added the supported-locale for this portlet as well.